# Goroutine never executed on Linux but work normally on Windows

Tags: go, goroutine

I am new to Go. After hours on google still could not find the explanation of this problem.
The code below run normally on Windows.
It run:

```
0
2
3
2A
```

and it wait forever, but the same code not working on Linux (Ubuntu), the goroutine never executed:

```
0
2
3
```

and it wait forever.

```
package main

import ("fmt")
var exit bool=false

func main(){
   fmt.Println("0")
   fmt.Println("2")
   go func() {
      fmt.Println("2A");
   }()
   fmt.Println("3")
   for {
        if exit {
           break
        }
   }
   fmt.Println("4")
}
```

Environment: Linux Ubuntu, go1.10.3 linux/amd64

Comment: A ran it on MacOs and received the same output with the windows one. Just an addition to the diagnosis

Comment: It is not about operating system. It is about goroutines which run depending on the priority queue of OS if the go routines return first, then it will print.

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger? How?

Comment: You don't have any explicit synchronization between your goroutines, thus you cannot have any expectation about their execution order. Your main goroutine is a "busy loop", which does not give any yielding points to the goroutine scheduler.

Comment: @icza regardless of the order, the 2A goroutine was never executed. I couldn't reproduce the issue in my debian box though. Stan are you running the same go version on windows?

Comment: But the main will never exit in his code.

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida the main will never exit because of never ending for loop.

Comment: @Rafael, yes i run the same go version on Windows.

Comment: @Rafael yes i'm aware of that. the problem is the goroutine never executed. These code is a minimized version of the real code. In the real code, the exit will be set true from another function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple explanation. It has nothing to do with operating systems. The behavior is the same on Linux and Windows.

```
$ go version
go version devel +f2ed3e1da1 Sat Aug 25 18:36:22 2018 +0000 linux/amd64
$

>go version
go version devel +e03220a594 Sat Aug 25 02:39:49 2018 +0000 windows/amd64
>
```

The `main` goroutine will effectively stop when it encounters the busy-wait spin loop:

```
for {
    if exit {
        break
    }
}
```

If we are only using one core then the entire program will stop. Otherwise, other goroutines can continue to run. The number of cores used is controlled by GOMAXPROCs up to a usable maximum of NumCPU.

`cores.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

var exit bool = false

func main() {
    fmt.Println("NumCPU:    ", runtime.NumCPU())
    if runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0) > runtime.NumCPU() {
        runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
    }
    fmt.Println("GOMAXPROCS:", runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0))

    fmt.Println("0")
    fmt.Println("2")
    go func() {
        fmt.Println("2A")
    }()
    fmt.Println("3")
    for {
        if exit {
            break
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("4")
}
```

Using one core, the Go scheduler ran the main goroutine. It didn't get a chance to run the 2A goroutine.

```
$ env GOMAXPROCS=1 go run cores.go
NumCPU:     4
GOMAXPROCS: 1
0
2
3
^Csignal: interrupt
$
```

Using more than one core, the Go scheduler ran the main and 2A goroutines.

```
$ env GOMAXPROCS=2 go run cores.go
NumCPU:     4
GOMAXPROCS: 2
0
2
3
2A
^Csignal: interrupt
$
```

Now, let's surrender the main goroutine with a Gosched() just before the spin loop to give other goroutines a chance to run.

`gosched.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

var exit bool = false

func main() {
    fmt.Println("NumCPU:    ", runtime.NumCPU())
    if runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0) > runtime.NumCPU() {
        runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
    }
    fmt.Println("GOMAXPROCS:", runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0))

    fmt.Println("0")
    fmt.Println("2")
    go func() {
        fmt.Println("2A")
    }()
    fmt.Println("3")
    runtime.Gosched()
    for {
        if exit {
            break
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("4")
}
```

Sharing one core, the main and 2A goroutines ran.

```
$ env GOMAXPROCS=1 go run gosched.go
NumCPU:     4
GOMAXPROCS: 1
0
2
3
2A
^Csignal: interrupt
$
```

Sharing two cores, the main and 2A goutines ran.

```
$ env GOMAXPROCS=2 go run gosched.go
NumCPU:     4
GOMAXPROCS: 2
0
2
3
2A
^Csignal: interrupt
$
```

---

NOTE: The Go scheduler behavior will likely change as the Go runtime is improved. For example, spin locks may not be allowed to monopolize a core.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run the same program on Go Playground. It will show the process took so long because of the never ending for loop.

```
for { // It is never ending for loop which never exit.
     if exit {
         break
     }
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/iCC6f6A4M1G)

But you cannot rely on the order of go routines. It is random. Also one thing you need to notice is that if you remove the for loop, The main will exit before your go routine will return the result.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var exit bool = false

func main() {
    fmt.Println("0")
    fmt.Println("2")
    go func() {
        fmt.Println("2A")
    }()
    fmt.Println("3")
    fmt.Println("4")
}
```

**Output**

```
0
2
3
4
```

Check it on [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VkpUF06tXlP)

As an advice it is always better to use wait groups in such situation where you want to wait for the go routine to finish before the main exit. Take for an example.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

var exit bool = false

func main() {
    fmt.Println("0")
    fmt.Println("2")
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        fmt.Println("2A")
    }()
    fmt.Println("3")
    fmt.Println("4")
    wg.Wait()
}
```

**Output**

```
0
2
3
4
2A
```

Working Code on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/us418wYFxUZ)

Comment: Downvoter my answer is absolutely correct. Please comment if you are downvoting with a reason.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you add a print statement inside of your for loop (or even a sleep),  you'll eventually see 2A being printed.

Go routines do not necessarily map each to a different CPU. Moreover, when they are both assigned to the same CPU, the execution will only be interrupted at certain library calls (such as Println).